# Setting static credentials with AWSS3 SDK in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services

I am trying to list objects in an AWS bucket in Swift on iOS.

I want to use static credentials for testing and debugging and can't figure out how to do it.
I am using the aws-sdk-swift AWSS3 package from https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-swift
I find the documentation pretty confusing, and multiple examples I have tried don't work, failing to find necessary functions in the sdk. I suspect part of the problem here is that there seem to be multiple sdks..

Here is my code so far (I haven't got far!). I get an error on the let client =..line "Cannot find 'accessKeyId' in scope"

```
import Foundation
import AWSS3
import AWSClientRuntime

func testAWS()
{
    let client = S3Client(region: "eu-west-2", credentials: {accessKeyId: "", secret: ""} )
}
```

What I am eventually trying to achieve is to list items in my bucket together with their metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Swift SDK developer guide doesn't really cover this at all, that's true. That's because directly authenticating using static credentials this way is no longer a recommended practice, and the guide tries to avoid going into it. That said, it's so commonly done during development that I wouldn't be surprised to see it added before the Swift SDK reaches version 1.0.0.

Anyway, the trick here is that you need to create a credentials provider object (in this case, an `AWSClientRuntime.StaticCredentialsProvider`), like this:

```swift
import Foundation
import AWSClientRuntime
import ClientRuntime
import AWSS3

func testAWS() {
    let config: S3Client.S3ClientConfiguration
    let credentials = AWSClientRuntime.Credentials(
        accessKey: "YOUR_ACCESS_KEY",
        secret: "YOUR_SECRET_KEY"
    )

    do {            
        let provider = try AWSClientRuntime.StaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)
        config = try S3Client.S3ClientConfiguration(
            region: "us-east-1",
            credentialsProvider: provider
        )
    } catch {
        /* handle the error */
    }

    let client = S3Client(config: config)
}
```

I hope that helps you out!

Comment: I should clarify: there are genuinely good reasons AWS now downplays this approach. Embedding keys in your code is a security risk in and of itself. There are better ways to authenticate now, and you're urged to use them. Documentation has (sort of) been updated to cover this, though more improvement could be helpful.

I should add: my opinions are my own and are not necessarily those of Amazon or Amazon Web Services. Or anyone I work with. Or my family or friends. Or anyone else, really. :)

Comment: Sure secrets should not be hardcoded, but this is still useful for cases where an api token is used for example for fetching temporary credentials and then response values are being used to generate the credentials object. For that reason the guide should still include this method.